# How to return the old value of an overridden property of HTMLElement?

Tags: javascript, overriding, element

I use the following method to override an HTMLElement property:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "style", {
    get: function () {
        var newValue = "some style...";
        return newValue;
    }
});
```

in the above example, I want to change the style property of HTMLElements. However, I want to return not overridden property (or the native property) in some cases. So far I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
var old = HTMLElement.prototype;
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "style", {
    get: function () {
        if (someCondition) {
            var newValue = "some style...";
            return newValue;
        } else {
            return old.style;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do that. Overridden is overridden. You could try to get the original property descriptor with `Object.getPropertyDescriptor` (or similar) but since this is a host object, it might not produce any useful result.

Comment: @Felix Kling: isn't it possible store the old property (before overriding) in some var?

Comment: I'm not sure how `style` works internally (and don't have the means to find out right now). If you would do the modifications on a per instance level then this might be possible.

Comment: I just had a look and `style` is a property of each element **instance**. It's not defined on `HTMLElement.prototype` and thus your changes don't have any effect anyway. So whatever you are trying to do, this is the wrong approach.

Comment: Thanks @Felix Kling for your attention. Well, using the above code I can change the style for the elements that are added using  JavaScript code. And to clear my goal, I'm actually developing an extension and in my extension I need to log the fonts that a web page is applying to elements. I figured out that I should override the getter functions of elements to find the font name that the web page applies. However, I don't know how to get the actual value of the style to find out the font name.

Comment: Accessing `style` will only give you the rules that have been directly assigned to the element, not the ones that are inherited via CSS. It seems more like you are looking for `window.getComputedStyle()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle. E.g. `window.getComputedStyle(element).fontFamily`

Comment: @Felix Kling: well window.getComputedStyle(element).fontFamily is for a specified element not all elements on the fly.

Comment: But overriding `HTMLElement.prototype.style` won't help you much either, since most styles are applied through CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Everything below has only been tested in Firefox 90 esr:

```
// A function to insert into a style change:
const showFonts = function (val) {
  console.log(val);
  return val;
};

// Save off the functions to be overridden:
var setfont1 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(CSS2Properties.prototype,'fontFamily').set;
var setfont2 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(CSS2Properties.prototype,'font-family').set;

// Now override them. 
// Call my function, then the original function:
Object.defineProperty(CSS2Properties.prototype,'fontFamily', 
  { set(val) {   setfont1.call(this,showFonts(val)); },
   enumerable: true,
   configurable: true});
Object.defineProperty(CSS2Properties.prototype,'font-family', 
  { set(val) {  setfont2.call(this,showFonts(val)); },
   enumerable: true,
   configurable: true});
```

To override almost anything in JS, including built-in functions, console.log the object that contains it, then dig down in the console to find the labels & arguments.

Then use the 'call' function.

Answer (score -1):

By assigning

```
var old = HTMLElement.prototype;
```

You are just making a pointer of the HTMLElement prototype, which is then overriden. Try instead creating a new prototype from the old one.

```
var old = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
```

Checkout:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: And how does this help the OP to achieve his goal? You are just adding one level of indirection. `old.style` would still access the overridden property `HTMLElement.prototype.style`.